# Can principal curvatures be complex numbers in a real world situation?

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics, curvature

Can the equation for the principal curvatures, $k^2 - 2Hk + K = 0$ (where H is equal to the mean curvature and K is equal to the Gaussian curvature), ever have complex roots?

In other words, where the roots are
$k_1 = H + \sqrt{H^2 - K}$ and
$k_2 = H - \sqrt{H^2 - K}$, will $H^2 - K$ ever be less than zero for some real-world object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "real-world" you mean a regular surface embedded in Euclidean $3$-space, then "no": The shape operator of a regular suface $S$ at a point $p$ is a symmetric operator on $T_{p}S$, so its eigenvalues $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ are real, and
$$
H^{2} - K
  = \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(k_{1} + k_{2})\bigr]^{2} - k_{1} k_{2}
  = \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(k_{1} - k_{2})\bigr]^{2}
  \geq 0.
$$

Comment: @Lauren:  You didn't want the justification of the inequality...? :)

Comment: Actually, that really would be appreciated too. I just took your word for it since I finally found it to be true from another source as well.

Comment: Just to check before I roll back the edit: The step that got edited out was an intermediate algebra step intended to make clear that $H^{2} - K$ is non-negative. Were there other details you weren't sure about?

Comment: No, just the validation of the statement that it's not negative would be great.